# Should this be multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[What data supports the benefits of telecommuting/working from home?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/446/telecommuting-working-from-home)

I think it is very on topic.  But it is very broad and there is no one right answer which makes it a bad question for here.

Is there value in changing it to ask specifically about the productivity, cost effectiveness, etc aspects.  I Think those specific questions are answerable in one answer.

None of the close reasons really fit but I do not think the question as it stands is a good fit for SE.

Comment: IMHO you can't really separate the issues because little cost effectiveness with significant loss of productivity makes it useless so if the data does exist it will be a combined study.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure about the question in question, but there are two indications that a question is too broad:

1. Would you expect there to be a whole book written to answer the question? Then the question is too broad. This is possibly the case with this question. However, a good answer *can* redeem this type of question.
2. Are there actually 2 or more questions explicitly stated in the question? In this case the question should be broken down into two or more separate questions addressing each question. That's not the case here.

The more specific the question the better the answers can be - but obviously don't make it *too* specific otherwise you run the risk of it being closed as too localised.

Answer (score 0):

To me the example question does seem like a single question. While only one answer can be accepted you can simply vote a few answers to the top and I would recommend that everybody should at least read the top few answers anyway just in case there is one that suits you better than the example.